# Rally SDK 2.0 RallyGrid Gives IndexOf Error When Clicking on Pages

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I have a rallygrid with only 3 items in it.  The grid automatically shows the links for showing 25/50/100/etc per page.  When I click on 50, say, I just get a constant spinner saying "Loading..."  and in the JS console, I get an uncaught error "Cannot call method 'indexOf'..."

I am assuming this means that my datastore is missing something?

Here's the grid stuff:

```
        var resultsModel = Ext.define('ResultsModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
            {name: 'FID', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'TestName', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'TestDuration', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Verdict', type: 'string'},
            ]       
        });
```

this.resultsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        model: 'ResultsModel',
                        pageSize: 25
                    });

```
        this.down('#testResults').add({
                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                store: this.resultsStore,
                width: 800,
                viewConfig: {
                stripeRows: true,
                emptyText: "No test cases run"
                },
                columnCfgs: [
                    {
                        text: 'TestCase', dataIndex: 'FID', width: 65 
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Test Name', dataIndex: 'TestName', flex: 1
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Run Time (s)', dataIndex: 'TestDuration', width: 75
                    },                      
                    {
                        text: 'Verdict', dataIndex: 'Verdict', width: 65, 
                        renderer: function(value){
                            if((value == "Fail") || (value == "Error")){
                                return Ext.String.format("<div style='background-color:#F00;color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>{0}</div>", value);
                            }
                            else{
                                return Ext.String.format("<div style='background-color:#2EFE2E;color:#000;font-weight:bold;text-align:center'>{0}</div>", value);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                ]
            });
```

and here's the data being shoved into the datastore:

```
    Ext.Array.each(data, function(record) {     
        records.push({
            FID: record.get('TestCase')['FormattedID'],  //record.data.TestCase might work too.
            TestName: record.get('TestCase')['Name'],
            TestDuration: record.get('Duration'),
            Verdict: record.get('Verdict')
        });
    });

    this.resultsStore.loadData(records, false);
```

The data in the array that Ext is iterating over is just a fetch of test runs.

Here's the console output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined sdk-debug.js:5304
Ext.apply.urlAppend sdk-debug.js:5304
Ext.define.buildUrl sdk-debug.js:26016
Ext.define.buildRequest sdk-debug.js:25859
Ext.define.doRequest sdk-debug.js:26059
Ext.define.read sdk-debug.js:25828
Ext.define.load sdk-debug.js:44668
Base.callParent sdk-debug.js:2894
Ext.define.load sdk-debug.js:45283
Ext.define.read sdk-debug.js:44420
Ext.define.loadPage sdk-debug.js:45562
Ext.define.changePageSize sdk-debug.js:96872
(anonymous function) sdk-debug.js:1540
(anonymous function)
wrap
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this example?

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/doc/#!/example/GridWithFreeformData

We created a store that plays nice with the grid and will automatically create a model and load your custom data for you.

Comment: I think the answer seems to be that I was having the script do this:  1. create an empty store, make an empty grid, go get the data and then use store.loadData to update the store & grid with the data.  But loadData makes it ignore the pagesize and the page numbers link seems to revert to the empty store.  So the answer seems to be to 1. get the data, create a store with the data, then create the grid.  That seems to be working.